# Selenium Web Scraping find_element_by_xpath always captures session string

Tags: python, performance, selenium, testing, xpath

I’m trying to capture the value ‘*Sources*’  shown on this website https://opennem.org.au/.

[image: The value im scraping]

Selenium’s *find_element_by_css_selector* is not working for me so  I’m using *find_element_by_xpath* instead.

This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://opennem.org.au/")
time.sleep(5.5)
elem=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[1]')

print(elem)
```

My **problem** is that whatever valid xpath string  I enter into the *find_element_by_xpath function*. I always get a result that looks like this:

```
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="e3bf293f8eed9026b04facd44231dab9", element="d3d5bb79-7799-457e-b044-bd580bbf5a30")>
```

**I can't get the actual value** and I have no idea why this function seems to capture the session evrytime. Hopefully someone is able shed some light on this.

Cheers all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 2 problems here:

1. You are using a wrong locator.
2. You should get the text from the web element, not to print the web element itself.

Try this:

```
summary_energy = driver.find_element_by_xpath('(//div[@class="summary-row"]//div[@class="summary-col-energy cell-value"]/span)[1]').text
print(summary_energy)
```

Comment: This totally worked for me! thank you so much @Prophet for your help!

Comment: Great! It's my pleasure :)

Comment: Just as a quick comment: 

I had to add the 'driver.' before find_element_by_xpath

So it ended up being like this:

summary_energy = driver.find_element_by_xpath('(//div[@class="summary-row"]//div[@class="summary-col-energy cell-value"]/span)[1]').text
print(summary_energy)

Comment: Ah, sure, thanks. It's 00:06 here, I have to go to the bed urgently :)